# Why would Jasmine Spyon not be called

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I have a test that is failing even though I am calling it. I am spying on the PrimeNG Message Service.

Below is some code that I have so far.

```
    it('should throw error', () => {
      const mockCall = spyOn(service, 'update$').and.throwError('Error');
      const msgService = spyOn(messageService, 'add').and.callThrough();
      expect(mockCall).toThrowError('Error');
      expect(msgService).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

I am expecting this to pass this test since it gets called withing my update$ observable if there is an error. Here is the error
"Expected spy add to have been called"

Comment: You're setting up your mocks, but you're not actually invoking any methods. What are you trying to test here? It looks like you forgot to actually test it.

Comment: I am trying to test the add function in the message Service. I thought the .callThrough() actually called the method.

Comment: Is `service.update` called in a lifecycle method such as `ngOnInit`?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger ah I see what you are talking about. Went ahead and called it below and it works fine. Thanks for pointing that out. i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb you should not apply mocks to the method you are testing. You should be calling the method you are testing directly, then verify what happened. You should also avoid verifying your mocks. You've set up `service.update$` to throw, that's what it will do, you do not need to verify it happened.

Your test should probably look something like this:

```
it('should throw error', () => {
    // Set up
    const mockCall = spyOn(service, 'update$').and.throwError('Error');

    // Test
    const message  = {};
    messageService.add(message);

    // Verify
    expect(mockCall).toHaveBeenCalledWith(message);
});
```